# Operands not working properly. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to fetch value from my table where price is greater than 500. I have tried following syntax:

```
$vehicles=vehicles::where('price','>',500)->get()->first();
```

But it is returning empty value. I have price greater than 500 in my table.

Strange thing is when i query following

```
$vehicles=vehicles::where('price','<',500)->get()->first();
```

It is returning value. This shouldn't happen because i don't have price less than 500. Can anyone help me?.

[image: I have attached values of price of my table]

Comment: Have you checked mysql query for the same. i.e. print mysql query for  your statement once.

Comment: In this case use **DB::enableQueryLog();** to get the query and fire it in your mysql terminal and check what happens

Comment: @jyotimishra when i did `SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE `price` > 500` in mysql. it is returning  value required.

Comment: Could you just check for `vehicles::where('price','>',500)->get();` or `vehicles::where('price','>',500)->first();`

Comment: @PaladiN Still returning empty value.

Comment: Could you check whether `vehicles` is the instance of your `vehicles model`?

Comment: @PaladiN Could it be due to string datatype i have used?

Comment: @Anon Yes! That is the problem. Because you are checking the `number` with `string`.

Comment: You could use attribute casting (not sure if it works for queries)
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
vehicles::where('price','>',500)->orderBy('price','ASC')->first();
```

It will give you the first row which has price > 500.
Change your string type as int(11).

> It is working in less than 500 query because it will convert your string price in integer and integer of a string is 0. then when you will run < 500 query then yes. zero is obviously less than 500 .

Comment: make your data type integer int (11)

Comment: So, why was it working when when i did vehicles::where('price','<',500)?

Comment: Ya that will work because it will convert your string price in integer and integer of a string is 0. then when you will run < 500 query then yes. zero is obviously less than 500 .

Answer (score 2):

Didn't find any issue in your where condition.
For retrieving list of all vehicles with price >500 you have to use:

```
$vehicles = vehicles::where(convert(integer, price),'>',500)->get();
```

For retrieving one vehicle with price >500 you have to use:

```
$vehicles=vehicles::where(convert(integer, price),'>',500)->first();
```

Comment: what is the datatype of price field? @Anon

Comment: Its string. @mith

Comment: above answer will work correctly for int/float field types